# can't figure out, have many differentfiles for this

Tags: java, driver

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class batavg
{

    private int hits = 0;
    private int tab = 0;
    private double ba;

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void battingaverage(double ba)
    {
        this.ba = ba;
    }

    public void avg()
    {
        this.avg = (double) (hits)/(tab);

        System.out.println("Number of hits are " + hits + " .");

    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class batdriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hits;
        batavg batter


        System.out.println("Enter number of hits: ");
        int hits = stdIn.nextInt();
        batavg batter = new batavg();
        batter.battingaverage(hits);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please be specific, what is the issue or error.

Comment: unclear what is asking

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) and 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6166/989)

Answer (score 0):

In java, all your public classes are kept in separate files with file names same as class name. FOr instance  class batavg will be written in file name batavg.java
so there will be2 separate files. For main function separate class is not necessarily required, you can write the main function in batavg class as well.